# Как преобразовать строку, построенному по данному правилу, в массив?

Tags: php

Строка, которую нужно преобразовать:

> ["products/February2020/orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg","products/February2020/BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg"]

Нужно сделать из нее массив следующего вида:

> products/February2020/orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg // первый элемент
>   products/February2020/BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg // второй элемент

Comment: А вы уверены, что это строка, а не просто какой то массив? что то вы не договариваете )) как вы получаете данную "строку" ?

Answer (score 1):

По всей вероятности вы не имеете понятия о типах данных.. то что вы показали, это должно быть массивом, вот пример:

```
$data= ["products/February2020/orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg","products/February2020/BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg"];

print_r($data);
```

Результат будет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => products/February2020/orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg
    [1] => products/February2020/BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg
)
```

Comment: я хочу получить так
<div class="slider single-product-nav">
                                        @foreach($page->images as $image)
                                            <img src="{{Voyager::image($image) }}">
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>

Comment: выдает ошибку  nvalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/professor/tiger/resources/views/product.blade.php)

Comment: php 
                                            print_r($page->images)endphp  показывает 
                                        ["products\/February2020\/ZBXpnY7bRDTkabcKqwl0.jpg","products\/February2020\/WRQPCFtYNrPsc37zT1rw.jpg"]

Comment: @junior  И как связан ваш пример в вопросе с  вторым примером? Насколько понятно, вы пытаетесь что то сделать в блейде ларавел, но(!) чтобы вам помочь, откорректируйте основной вопрос и постарайтесь описать полную картину с примерами вашего кода, телепаты уже давно спят.. )))